# How to use Observe() to execute updated data?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a plot that changes according to the user's choice of data.
Here is a snippet of my program:

```
data <- data.frame(
  Animal = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  Count = c(20, 14, 23),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

observeEvent(input$load_data,{
  if(isTruthy(input$selectzoo == "ZOO A")){
    data <- data.frame(
      Animal = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
      Count = c(12, 33, 8),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  } else if(isTruthy(input$selectzoo == "ZOO B")){
    data <- data.frame(
      Animal = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
      Count = c(4, 22, 34),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  } 
})

observe({
  output$plot_zoo <- renderPlotly({
      plot_animal(data$Animal,as.numeric(data$Count))
  })
})
```

I have default data to show first. And after the user selects "input$selectzoo", the plot should display "data" according to the options in ObserveEvent(). But it turns out that Observe() will select the data declared first.

Is there a way for Observe() to execute the latest data according to the user's choice?

Comment: On a different note, as of R 4.0, `stringsAsFactors` will default to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(shiny)

# default
data <- data.frame(
  Animal = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
  Count = c(20, 14, 23),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("selectzoo", "selectzoo", choices = c("default", "ZOO A", "ZOO B")),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected_data <- reactive({
    switch (input$selectzoo,
      "default" = data,
      "ZOO A" = {
        data.frame(
          Animal = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
          Count = c(12, 33, 8),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
      },
      "ZOO B" = {
        data.frame(
          Animal = c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys"),
          Count = c(4, 22, 34),
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
      }
    )
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable(selected_data())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```